# With MongoDB, can I sort on the parent document, and then on a child array?

Tags: mongodb

I'm reading a about aggregation in search of solving my issue, but I'm not sure if its best for my case, or perhaps I need to re-model how I'm storing the data.

Consider the following Document:

```
{
    title: "ParentCategory",
    sort: 1,
    children: [
        {
            title: "ChildA",
            sort: 1,
        },
        {
            title: "ChildB",
            sort: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

And the following query:

```
db.Categories.find({},
    {
        sort: { sort: 1 }
    }
);
```

I want to sort first by the parent categories... that's no problem. But I also want the child categories to obey the sort order.

I've read suggestions to order them in the array that I want them, not using the sort field, and also read about aggregation, but seemed complex for this. Perhaps I should be modeling the data differently. I want to easily be able to change a sort for a particular category or child category later for certain reasons.

Tried using:

```
sort: { "sort" : 1, "children.sort" : 1 }
```

That didn't work.

Sorry for the newbie question. New to Mongo... like really new.

Comment: If you need to sort the child documents in > 1 way commonly, then storing them in one sorted order in an array in a parent document probably isn't the best design. It's hard to say what a good design is without an idea of the use case, but a range of options for modeling parent-child relationships is described in the [MongoDB data modeling docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably more efficient to keep the arrays sorted in the collection instead of sorting them on every query. Do the sort on the array before inserting the document, and every time you push an element into the array make mongo re-sort the array for you, like this,

```
db.cateegories.update(
{...},  // query
{
  "$push": {
    "children": {
      "$each": [ {
                 "title" : "ChildC",
                 "sort" : 3
                 }, ... 
               ],
      "$sort": {"sort" : 1}
    }
  }
}
)
```

see more info [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort).